# I get thrown 166 errors when i try compiling appCompat to my gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

When i try compiling compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' to my gradle it throws me all these errors. I'm not sure how to get appcompat into my project.

Here is my gradle for my app.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myegotest.ego_17012016"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile project(':SlidingMenuLib-master')
}
```

Here is my gradle for my SlidingMenu module.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'

    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the errors i'm getting.

```
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\AndroidStudioProjects\Ego-17012016\SlidingMenuLib-master\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(79) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(79) Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(79) Attribute "divider" has already been defined
Error:(79) Attribute "background" has already been defined
Error:(79) Attribute "backgroundSplit" has already been defined
Error:(96) Attribute "navigationMode" has already been defined
Error:(96) Attribute "displayOptions" has already been defined
Error:(96) Attribute "title" has already been defined
Error:(96) Attribute "subtitle" has already been defined
Error:(96) Attribute "icon" has already been defined
Error:(96) Attribute "logo" has already been defined
Error:(96) Attribute "backgroundStacked" has already been defined
Error:(96) Attribute "customNavigationLayout" has already been defined
Error:(96) Attribute "homeLayout" has already been defined
Error:(96) Attribute "progressBarStyle" has already been defined
Error:(96) Attribute "indeterminateProgressStyle" has already been defined
Error:(96) Attribute "progressBarPadding" has already been defined
Error:(96) Attribute "itemPadding" has already been defined
Error:(99) Attribute "initialActivityCount" has already been defined
Error:(99) Attribute "expandActivityOverflowButtonDrawable" has already been defined
Error:(102) Attribute "preserveIconSpacing" has already been defined
Error:(103) Attribute "iconifiedByDefault" has already been defined
Error:(103) Attribute "queryHint" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "windowActionBar" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "windowActionBarOverlay" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "windowActionModeOverlay" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionBarTabStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionBarTabBarStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionBarTabTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionOverflowButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionBarStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionBarSplitStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionBarWidgetTheme" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionBarSize" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionBarDivider" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionBarItemBackground" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionMenuTextAppearance" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionMenuTextColor" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionModeStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionModeCloseButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionModeBackground" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionModeSplitBackground" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionModeCloseDrawable" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionModeShareDrawable" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionModePopupWindowStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "textAppearanceLargePopupMenu" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionDropDownStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "dropdownListPreferredItemHeight" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "spinnerDropDownItemStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "homeAsUpIndicator" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "actionButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "selectableItemBackground" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "dividerVertical" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "activityChooserViewStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "popupMenuStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "textAppearanceSearchResultTitle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "textColorSearchUrl" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "listPreferredItemHeightSmall" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "listPreferredItemPaddingLeft" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "listPreferredItemPaddingRight" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "dropDownListViewStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "listPopupWindowStyle" has already been defined
Error:(110) Attribute "textAppearanceListItemSmall" has already been defined
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\AndroidStudioProjects\Ego-17012016\SlidingMenuLib-master\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\values-v11\values.xml
Error:(46, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(53, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(60, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(67, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\AndroidStudioProjects\Ego-17012016\SlidingMenuLib-master\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\values-v14\values.xml
Error:(4, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(12, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(20, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(28, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\AndroidStudioProjects\Ego-17012016\SlidingMenuLib-master\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\values-v21\values.xml
Error:(112, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(112, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(112, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(112, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(112, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(112, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(150, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(150, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(150, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(150, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(150, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(150, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(188, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(188, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(188, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(188, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(188, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(188, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(226, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(226, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(226, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(226, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(226, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(226, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(296, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(309, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\AndroidStudioProjects\Ego-17012016\SlidingMenuLib-master\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(19) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(245) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(246) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(247) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(254) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:(258) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
Error:(262) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
Error:(266) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(5) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(6) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(7) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(8) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(9) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(10) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(11) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(12) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(14) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(16) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(17) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(21) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(22) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(23) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(25) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(26) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(27) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
Error:(28) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(29) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(30) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(31) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(32) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(36) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(38) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(43) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
Error:(44) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
Error:(47) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
Error:(53) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
Error:(60) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
Error:(214) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(215) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(216) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(217) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(218) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(226) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(227) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:(228) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(229) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(230) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(231) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(232) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(237) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:(238) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(239) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:(240) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(248) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(253) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':SlidingMenuLib-master:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't use together** these libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

They use the **same attrs**.

Also there are no reason to use [ABS](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) today.

> ActionBarSherlock is deprecated. No more development will be taking place. For an up-to-date action bar backport use AppCompat.

**Remove the ActionBarSherlock and use only the AppCompat.**

Also in you library you can't use  `compileSdkVersion 17` since you are using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1`.
You have to compile with API 23, so change to

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```